# How to make Selenium IDE Test stop and wait for user actions?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, recaptcha, selenium-ide

I'm trying to automate a process in a website using Selenium IDE, but there's a reCaptcha on the page and I want Selenium to stop and wait for the user to solve the captcha, so I only have to solve the captcha. How do I make it stop and wait for me to solve the recaptcha?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you know the next website you can use this code

```
while driver.current_url != "the next website":
    time.sleep(1)
```

it's simple put it in the time you need to do recaptcha then when you go to the next website the while loop will break